*** AutoTeX ABORTING *** when submitting a successfully compiled overleaf project to arXiv
*** AutoTeX ABORTING *** when submitting a successfully compiled overleaf project (pdflatex 2023) to arXiv
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `TII-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using dr
aft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.179 \item t
he publicly available source code, executable file (Android...

?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.179 \item t
he publicly available source code, executable file (Android...

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'main.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.aux' (1719826390 >= 1719826389)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.out' (1719826390 >= 1719826389)
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2023/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/5702084/ && tex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=tex)
(./main.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[journal,twoside,web]{ieeecolor}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1

No pages of output.
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: tex 'main.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'main.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***

[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.

[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Are you using eps figures in a doc to be compiled using pdflatex? Might be better to either ask for a latex run, or manually convert the eps to pdf. It might to be safe to assume that the system at the other end autoconvert.

You are for some reason running tex instead of pdflatex.

Looks similar but not the same Arxiv: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange

You submitted a file that probably use both .jpg/png files and .eps files. This works on Overleaf because it executes epstopdf in the background.
On arXiv, execution of external programs is disabled, thus the automatic conversion from eps to pdf is not working.
You have two options:

Either include the generated pdf as mentioned above in your submission
Include a pdf/jpg/png version of the respective graphics.

